Find $x^\circ$ in the quadrilateral $ABDC$ below
If $AB = CD$ then find $x^\circ$
(Answer: $30^\circ$)

I try:
$\angle C = 60^\circ$
$\angle ABC = 180^\circ -(2\theta +\theta) = 180^\circ -3\theta$
$\angle BDC = 180^\circ - (x+60^\circ -\theta) = 120^\circ -x+\theta$
$\therefore x = 120^\circ +\theta - \angle BDC$
How do I finish?

I suppose $\angle C=60°$ was a given condition, right? If so, please include that into your question.

@I No...The question is exactly as it was created and the image is a faithful copy of the original. $\angle C = \theta +60-\theta = 60^o$

I see: they give $\angle BCD=60°-\theta$. That is not clear from the text, however.

@Intelligentipauca  n these Peruvian questions they do not always mention the information in the text but they put it in the image itself, such as the equality of the sides through dots placed on them.

There is a video about a very similar problem: https://youtu.be/CyNdjy9eSco?si=GSB4ON4Qi7AeRVYu (time: 3:40)

Solution:
Take $E$ on $AC$ such that $\angle BEA=2\theta$, so $BE=BA$. Also because of this, $\angle CBE=\theta$, which means $BE=EC$. So $EC=BE=BA=DC$ which means $EC=DC$ and with $\angle DCE=60^\circ$ we have $\triangle DCE$ is equilateral so $DC=DE=CE=BE$. Therefore, $x^\circ=\angle DBE-\angle CBE=(90^\circ-\angle DEB/2)-(90^\circ-\angle CEB/2)=\angle DEC/2=30^\circ.$

Excellent...thanks for help

JetfiRex, there is a mistake in your answer indeed you wrote $x^\circ=\angle DBE-\angle DCE$ instead of $x^\circ=\angle DBE-\angle CBE$

@Angelo Thanks, fixed!

JetfiRex, congratulations for your solution. I like it so much and I have already upvoted it.

Nice thinking , though I have a Doubt here : When you got $\triangle DCE$ is Equilateral , how did you get $CE = BD$ ?

@Prem It is a typo, sorry. It should be $CE=BE$. Fixed.

Depending on where the Question came from , we can consider Heuristic Solutions, Eg when we are given Multiple Options like $15^\circ,30^\circ,45^\circ,60^\circ$ , while the Solution turns out to be $30^\circ$.
Since $x$ is independent of $\theta$ , we can take $2\theta=60$
Diagram will then turn out like Equilateral triangle which has been cut at the Mid-Points to get a line Parallel to Base.
While $\triangle ABC$ has angles $60^\circ,30^\circ,90^\circ$ , we can check that $\angle ABD=120^\circ$
That will leave $x=30^\circ$ , which will eliminate all other Options.

Nice shortcut...

@Intelligentipauca, really do you think this answer is nice ?

@Angelo Yes, why not? It's a clever shortcut for this kind of questions.

@Intelligentipauca, I think a clever answer is what JetfiRex wrote
